# Why do we plot $y$ vs. $(x-x_{off})^2$ instead of just $y$ vs. $(x-x_{off})$?

Tags: regression, estimation

We created graphs in my lab related to electric field strength, and we plotted $y$ vs. $(x-x_{off})^2$. Why is this done? Why didn't we simply plot $(x-x_{off})$?

Comment: What do you mean by $x_{off}$?

Comment: Seems off-topic here, so to speak: doesn't the answer lie in the physics?

Comment: Why not ask the people who made the graph / the decision to use $(x-x_{off})$?

Answer (score 2):

Off topic for cross-validated, but I do know the answer.

Electric strength can be defined as:
$ E = \frac{k*Q}{d^2} $

where $Q$ is the source charge, $k$ is a constant $9.0*10^9 N*m^2/C^2$, and $d$ is the distance from the source charge.

Note the $d$ is squared which would explain why the plots are the squared distances. It adheres to the mathematics of the equation.

Comment: +1, but surely $d$ is the distance in your middle para.

Comment: @Nick Cox good catch $d$ is the distance $d^2$ is the distance squared.

Comment: It's a case of everyone knows what you mean but getting it right still beats the opposite.